# Will missing salah be forgiven and not punished for?? And can a hafidh go hell?

Tags: salat, forgiveness, jahannam, salat-qada

I saw this and started crying.. is it true because I’m very scared and asked for forgiveness:
The Messenger of Allah (pbuh) said, “A person neglecting his Salat (even though he makes it up later) shall remain in Jahannam for a period of one huqb.
Please tell me how I can save myself and is it possible for a hafidh to go to hell?

Comment: A hafidh can go to hell, a scholar can go to hell etc. there's a qudsi hadith on this subject (See in [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1905a). Intention is the key and doing things for the right cause too. Be aware that none has a ticket to jannah in his pocket the prophet himself even warned his daughter and relatives although they were Muslims and believers! Further repentance is the key a person must sincerely repent to be forgiven by Allah. Note that your questions are rather advise requests and therefore hardly fitting the site's policy!

Answer (score -1):

The one who missed it for a reason, such as falling asleep or forgetting it. There is no sin on him in this case, but he has to make it up when he wakes up or remembers it.

> It was narrated from Anas ibn Maalik (may Allaah be pleased with him)
> that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said:
> “Whoever forgets a prayer, let him offer it as soon as he remembers,
> for there is no expiation for it other than that.” Narrated by
> al-Bukhaari (572) and Muslim (684); Muslim narrated an additional
> phrase: “or sleeps and misses it”.

> Muslim also narrated (684): “If one of you sleeps and misses a prayer,
> or forgets it, let him offer the prayer when he remembers, for Allaah
> says ‘and perform As‑Salaah (Iqaamat‑as‑Salaah) for My remembrance’
> [Ta-Ha 20:14].”

But the one **who missed the prayer with no excuse; rather he ignored it until the time for it ended**, out of laziness and carelessness. This person is sinning according to the consensus of the Muslims, and **has committed a major sin.**

*Ibn Hazm said:*

> As for the one who deliberately omits to pray until the time for the
> prayer ends, he can never make it up, so he should do a lot of good
> deeds and offer a lot of voluntary prayers, so that his balance (of
> good deeds) will weigh heavily on the Day of Resurrection, and he
> should repent and ask Allaah for forgiveness. End quote.

### How you can save yourself

The more correct view – and Allaah knows best – is that the one who deliberately omits the prayer should not make it up, **rather he has to seek forgiveness and repent.**

*Shaykh al-Islam Ibn Taymiyah said:*

> ...but the sin of missing and delaying the prayer beyond its
> prescribed time is like any other sin, **it needs either repentance or
> good deeds that will erase it or other things that will waive the
> punishment.**

[Source And read the full article](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/111783/how-can-he-make-up-for-missed-prayers)